# How does Android Monitor (in Android Studio) work?

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, profiling, adb

Android Studio has a useful tool, *Android Monitor*, to profile and analyze app resources usage.

[image]

My question is how does it work? Does it use `adb` commands to collect app/emulator runtime information like method call traces or memory statistics? Or does it use any other approaches?

I would appreciate if someone could give some documentation or examples about how it is implemented.

Comment: AS is open source... so take a look at it https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/adt/idea/+/studio-master-dev/android/src/com/android/tools/idea/monitor/cpu/CpuSampler.java

Comment: @AlexP. Thanks for your info. I just checked the repo and found there are two folders/repos. One is `android/platform/tools/idea` and other is `android/platform/tools/adt/idea`. Which one is the right folder for current android-plugin for idea?